# Visual Studio 2008 Report Designer (complex general ledger)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, reporting, report-designer

I'm combining reports to create a single general ledger report, currently it consists of 84 seperate reports.  My idea is the end user will have a drop down for the department and month.  These are my columns:

Account Number    Account Description     Current Period Actual

YTD Actual        YTD Budget              YTD Budget Variance

Total YR Budget   Account Status

I have most of it figured out, but can't understand how to figure YTD Actual and YTD Budget since these will require a Sum of multiple Fields depending on what month and department is selected.

My where statement goes something like this and takes care of the current period actual and account number:

Where 
         ( gl_master.acct_cde = gl_master_comp_v.acct_cde ) and
         ( gl_master.budget_officer = budget_off_mstr.budget_officer ) and
         ( ( gl_master_comp_v.acct_comp1 = '01' ) AND
         ( budget_off_mstr.budget_officer IN (@BudgetOfficer) ) ) AND
     ((@Month = 1 AND gl_master.post_bal_mon_1) OR
      (@Month = 2 AND gl_master.post_bal_mon_2)...

How can I have the query recognize what needs to be put into the column when there are multiple fields being summed.

Thanks for any insight.  If you made something like this before a small sample of it would be very helpful.

Comment: I can only see three ways of doing this: Build it in query, computed expression in textbox w/ some type of case statement, a calculated field in the dataset except no aggregate functions can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out.

It needs to be done in a calculated field within the dataset.  Then a sum can be done on the field in the textbox.

small chunk of calculated field:

```
=Cdec(Switch(Parameters!Month.Value = 1, Fields!post_bal_mon_1.Value,
Parameters!Month.Value = 2, Fields!post_bal_mon_2.Value + Fields!post_bal_mon_1.Value, 
Parameters!Month.Value = 3, Fields!post_bal_mon_3.Value + Fields!post_bal_mon_1.Value + Fields!
post_bal_mon_2.Value, 
Parameters!Month.Value = 4, Fields!post_bal_mon_4.Value + Fields!post_bal_mon_1.Value + Fields!  
post_bal_mon_2.Value + Fields!post_bal_mon_3.Value,...))
```

textbox for sum(I place this in footer):

```
=SUM(Fields!post_bal_mon_1.value, "DataSet1")
```